# VB script - If clause with hex const

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, constants, hex

I'm analyse a VB script with a if clause I don't understand. It works like this:

```
Const current_status_01 = &H1480781
Const current_status_02 = &H204a2780
Const status_1 = &h00002000
Const status_2 = &h00100000

If (current_status_01 And status_1) Or (current_status_01 And status_2) Then
    MsgBox "True", VBOKOnly, "If 1"
Else
    MsgBox "False", VBOKOnly, "If 1"
End if

If (current_status_02 And status_1) Or (current_status_02 And status_2) Then
    MsgBox "True", VBOKOnly, "If 2"
Else
    MsgBox "False", VBOKOnly, "If 2"
End if
```

Could someone please explain me why the first if condition is false and the second one is true? It would be nice if someone could write this example in Python too for my understanding.

Thank you!

Comment: Because it is doing a [bitwise comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/e8zy95hw(v=vs.84)), next question.

Comment: Just for completeness if you come across this code and wonder what is going on, the developer is using bitwise comparison to store bit flags. By comparing the bitmask with the flag they can determine if a certain value is switched on or off. I'm guessing though that the constants are not just set at the top like that otherwise the code would be pointlessly over complex and not make much sense.

Comment: I think i got it. The binary 1 in the fourth octett of the AND result of the second statement will result in true for the hole statement.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but only if once all the bits are compared the results match. If you think about it, it's just a clever way of storing switches, say you have 1 byte, you can hold a maximum of 8 flags, but you can also switch off and on any of those flags in various combinations. Bitmasks are a cool concept, but whether you need it in this instance entirely depends on code and it's complexity.

Comment: You are doing implicit maths. Make it explicit - `If current_status_02 And status_1 = status_1 then`.